# What's wrong with my input? I keep getting errors that h is not defined

Tags: python, input

```
else:
        hs = raw_input("HIT OR SHAME YOUR FOREFATHERS! (h or s): ").lower()
        if h in s:
            player.append(rc(cards))
        else:
            break
```

I keep getting an error saying that h is not defined, no matter which one you choose.

Comment: Because it's not. You want `if hs == 'h':`.

Answer (score 0):

Answering what @chepner commented:

```
hs = raw_input("HIT OR SHAME YOUR FOREFATHERS! (h or s): ").lower()
if hs == 'h':
    player.append(rc(cards))
else:
    break
```

Or shorter:

```
hs = raw_input("HIT OR SHAME YOUR FOREFATHERS! (h or s): ").lower()
if hs != 'h': break
player.append(rc(cards))
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code

```
hs = raw_input("HIT OR SHAME YOUR FOREFATHERS! (h or s): ").lower()
    if h in s:
        player.append(rc(cards))
    else:
        break
```

Instead of

```
 if h in s
```

compare

```
'h' in hs
```

I think that's what you missed there.